# Redmine Plugin: Accessing RedmineCRM Agile Plugin

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

i´m totally new to Redmine and need to evaluate agile project management solutions. I installed a fresh Redmine 2.5 on a Ubuntu Server 14.04 and the [RedmineCRM Agile Plugin](http://www.redminecrm.com/projects/agile/pages/1) using the official [instructions](http://www.redminecrm.com/projects/agile/pages/2).

After restarting Redmine i was able to access the plugin configuration, what makes me assume that the plugin is installed correct.

How can i access the web interface of the plugin? When i login to Redmine as administrator or User (with permissions to see the agile board) i only see the usual Redmine UI [image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Atlassian it is [RedmineCRM](http://www.redminecrm.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=smm&utm_campaign=atlassian_agile_redmine) :)

Anyway, to activate agile module you should go to specific project Settings -> Modules and enable "Agile" and "Issues" module. Make sure you add specific permissions for your redmine users/roles.

Here is a guide: http://www.redminecrm.com/boards/39/topics/1493-how-to-allow-non-admin-users-view-and-manage-agile-boards

Comment: Thank you for your response. I clarified the question

Comment: You need issues module enabled as well